# remove new line if next line does not begin with a number

Tags: file, sed

I have a file that is like

```
    1 test
    test
```

How can I remove the new line from the so the final output becomes:

`1 test test`

I already tried some sed but I could not het it to work.

Comment: You can use `tr` like `tr '\n' ' ' < myfile.txt` to remove new line

Comment: but how do i check if the next line does not starts width a number? and then remove the previous linebreak. All the things apart can i but i can not combine them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can be a bit smarter and print a new line before the line if it starts with a digit (except for the first line);

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS="";} NR==1 { print; next; } /^[[:digit:]]/ { print "\n"; print; next; } { print; }'
```

The awk script:

```
BEGIN { ORS=""; }                            # default: no newline between output records
NR==1 { print; next; }                       # first line: print
/^[[:digit:]]/ { print "\n"; print; next; }  # if starts with a digit: print newline before
{print;}                                     # other lines (next; has not been called yet)
```

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick:

```
sed -n '$!{ 1{x;d}; H}; ${ H;x;s|\n\([^0-9]\)| \1|g;p}' inputfile
```

**Input:**

```
1 test1
test1
2 test2
test2
test2
3 test3
4 test4
```

**Output:**

```
1 test1 test1
2 test2 test2 test2
3 test3
4 test4
```

Comment: How can this script be adapted so that instead of a digit the next line can be any pattern

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved if an explanation of the command was given (as in @brandizzi's)

Comment: among so many answers on the internet this is the only one that worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty simple to accomplish with sed. Consider the file below

```
$ cat numbered                      
1 abc
def
ghi
2 jkl
mno
3 pqr
4 stu
vxw
```

The command `sed '/^[0-9]/{N; s/\n/ /;}' numbered` will do the trick:

```
$ sed '/^[0-9]/{N; s/\n/ /;}' numbered
1 abc def
ghi
2 jkl mno
3 pqr 4 stu
vxw
```

How it works: first, it verifies if the current line does start with a digit:

```
/^[0-9]/
```

The `/^[0-9]/` is an [address](http://linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq3_006.html) and matches only lines which starts with a digit. Iff some line matches it, the the command following the address will be executed.

In this case, this command is a `{`, which opens a function list. The function list will aggregate two or more commands as if they where only one. In this case, we have two commands in the function list. The first one is the `N` command:

```
N
```

This command appends a newline and the next line to the pattern space. The next line will not be considered anymore after the current cycle. The next command is `s///` which replaces newlines by a space:

```
s/\n/ /
```

So, the newline appended by `N` will be replaced by a space. Then, we need just to close the function list with `}`. The result will be:

```
/^[0-9]/{
    N
    s/\n/ /
}
```

Since I've put all commands in one line for brevity, the commands inside the function list should be separated by semicolons:

```
/^[0-9]/{N;s/\n/ /;}
```

Note that if a line starting by a digit follows another line starting by a digit, the following line will be joined to the previous one and the command will apply to it.

Answer (score -1):

A solution using 'sed':

Input file (infile):

```
1 test
test
2 two 
3 three
4 four
five 
six
7 seven
eight
9 nine
```

'Sed' program (script.sed):

```
/[0-9]\+/ {
        : a 
        N
        /\n[0-9]\+/ {
                P
                s/.*\n//
        }
        t a
}

y/\n/ /
```

Execution:

```
$ sed -f script.sed infile
```

Output:

```
1 test test
2 two
3 three
4 four five 
six
7 seven eight
9 nine
```