# remove new line if next line does not begin with an expression

Tags: bash, awk, sed

My CSV file has columns like

```
start_time,end_time,link

1407233497,1407233514,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=streamingstats&fmt=n
1407233498,1407233515,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=cenjreaecnjcd
mingstats&fmt=n
1407233499,1407233516,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=weedwcecd
```

Some times link contains new lines and I want to remove them.
How can I do that the new line from the so the final output becomes:

```
1407233497,1407233514,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=streamingstats&fmt=n
1407233498,1407233515,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=cenjreaecnjcdmingstats&fmt=n
1407233499,1407233516,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=weedwcecd
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588113/remove-new-line-if-next-line-does-not-begin-with-a-number) and I tried something like that

```
sed -n '$!{ 1{x;d}; H}; ${ H;x;s|\n\([^1-9]d{10}\)| \1|g;p}'
```

but it doesn't work

I would be really appreciate for help, because I got stuck with this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is awk-oneliner:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", (NR>1&&/^[0-9]{10}/?"\n":""),$0}END{print ""}' file
```

see this test:

```
kent$  cat f
1407233497,1407233514,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=streamin
gstats&fmt=n
1407233498,1407233515,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=cenjreaecnjcd
mi
ngstats&fmt=n
1407233499,140723
3516,http://s.yout
ube.com/stream_204?event=weedwcecd

kent$  awk '{printf "%s%s", (NR>1&&/^[0-9]{10}/?"\n":""),$0}END{print ""}' f
1407233497,1407233514,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=streamingstats&fmt=n
1407233498,1407233515,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=cenjreaecnjcdmingstats&fmt=n
1407233499,1407233516,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=weedwcecd
```

Comment: Thanks, you save my day)
I need to spend a weekend with awk to know each other closer

Comment: @Kent do you know any reason why `[0-9]{10}` would not work ?

Comment: @Jidder which context?? doesn't work in my awk line? or what?

Comment: @hash3r Im happy if that line helps.

Comment: @Jidder which awk do you have? try adding `--re-interval` after your `awk`

Comment: @Jidder if you have `gnu-awk` < `4.00` you need to use `--re-interval` to use regex like `{10}`

Comment: `GNU Awk 3.1.8`. `--re-interval` seems to have worked though thanks :) @Jotne Ahh right that will be why then !

Comment: @Kent may be you know how can I check that 10th symbol is comma.
may be it would be faster?

Comment: I don't see why it would. Marginally slower in that there is one more character to match (but this would not be noticeable). The expression is already anchored at start of line so it will fail fast if it cannot succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below perl oneliner command,

```
perl -0777pe 's/\n(?!\d{10},|$)//g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
1407233497,1407233514,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=streamin
gstats&fmt=n
1407233498,1407233515,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=cenjreaecnjcd
mi
ngstats&fmt=n
1407233499,140723
3516,http://s.yout
ube.com/stream_204?event=weedwcecd
```

---

```
$ perl -0777pe 's/\n(?!\d{10},|$)//g' file
1407233497,1407233514,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=streamingstats&fmt=n
1407233498,1407233515,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=cenjreaecnjcdmingstats&fmt=n
1407233499,1407233516,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=weedwcecd
```