# Check exactly Nth symbol is comma

Tags: bash, awk, sed, text-processing

My CSV file has columns like

```
start_time,end_time,link

1407233497,1407233514,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=streamingstats&fmt=n
1407233498,1407233515,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=cenjreaecnjcd
mingstats&fmt=n
1407233499,1407233516,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=weedwcecd
```

Some times link contains new lines and I want to remove them. How can I do that the new line from the so the final output becomes:

```
1407233497,1407233514,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=streamingstats&fmt=n
1407233498,1407233515,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=cenjreaecnjcdmingstats&fmt=n
1407233499,1407233516,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=weedwcecd
```

I was proposed with this awk one-liner:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", (NR>1&&/^[0-9]{10}/?"\n":""),$0}END{print ""}' file
```

It works great, but may be it would be faster to check that 10th symbol is comma?

New line character is possible only inside the link and link can't contain commas

I would be really appreciate for help

Comment: I would guess that the `awk` you have will be faster than one that needs to count `,` to get new line. You only have two `,` in each line here.

Comment: So you have a working awk program and you want what, a faster one?  If this is a performance optimization question, you should include sample inputs, current timings, and target timings.

Comment: @hash you mean there may be a possibility of multiple newline character in the link section?

Comment: But the 10th character is a number not comma.

Comment: Link to original question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25564603/2088135. Note that as mentioned in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25564818/2088135), the `--re-interval` switch must be used to make it work with gawk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's best when posting questions to ask how to solve a problem rather than how to implement a specific solution to a problem as the solution you come up with or are given may not be the best one for your problem.

This would be the more natural way to solve your problem and it just happens to be faster than the solution you had asked for:

```
$ awk -F, '{printf "%s%s",(NR>1&&NF>2?RS:""),$0} END{print ""}' file
1407233497,1407233514,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=streamingstats&fmt=n
1407233498,1407233515,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=cenjreaecnjcdmingstats&fmt=n
1407233499,1407233516,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=weedwcecd
```

Using @TomFenechs 242M sample input file:

```
$ time awk '{printf "%s%s", (NR>1&&/^[0-9]{10}/?"\n":""),$0}END{print ""}' file > kent.out

real    0m17.542s
user    0m16.738s
sys     0m0.530s

$ time awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR>1&&NF>2{print a,b}NF>2{a=$1OFS$2;b=$3;next}{b=b$0}END{print a,b}' file > tom.out

real    0m13.826s
user    0m13.213s
sys     0m0.374s

$ time awk -F, '{printf "%s%s",(NR>1&&NF>2?RS:""),$0} END{print ""}' file > ed.out

real    0m10.785s
user    0m10.030s
sys     0m0.467s
```

Comment: I'm actually surprised the results are that close since string concatenation is typically even slower than I/O in awk, and you're doing it for every input line (`a=$1OFS$2` or `b=b$0`). I suspect it must be my printf vs your print leveling the playing field a bit. You could probably speed yours up a bit by moving the test for `NF>2` to just one location then using `if(NR>1)print a,b` inside its action block.

Comment: @EdMorton BSD `awk` still took over 35 seconds for the last variant. GNU awk v4.1 clocked it at 10.4.

Comment: @Ed you were right about removing the duplicate test (I've updated my answer again). Still not as fast as your version though.

Comment: @jaypal was that on the 3rd invocation of the command or the first? How did the other solutions fare with BSD awk (3rd invocations timings only please)?

Comment: @EdMorton I didn't notice any improvements due to caching. Here are three runs on BSD `awk` and GNU `awk` for [solution1](http://cl.ly/XIyw), [solution2](http://cl.ly/XJ6K) and [solution3](http://cl.ly/XIZD). Input file was created the same way as you and Tom did.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like BSD awk always uses about 36 seconds no matter which solution or how many times you execute it. Thanks.

Comment: @Ed Thanks for your solution!
Could you tell me please, how can I change script if I have 4 columns instead 3
Thanks one more time

Comment: You're welcome. Please think about it and you tell us how you'd do it. It's important you understand what the script is doing so you can write/modify your own going forward. Hint: look up the meaning of `NF` in the man page.

Comment: I've done it! 
NF - number of fields in the current record
awk -F, '{printf "%s%s",(NR>1&&NF>22?RS:""),$0} END{print ""}' for 23 columns
awk not so hard as it seems, sorry for my annoying)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you could do it (I assume that there are no leading lines in the file):

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
NF>2 { if (NR>1) print a, b; a = $1 OFS $2; b = $3; next }
{ b = b $0 }
END { print a, b }
```

Testing it out:

```
$ awk -f join.awk file
1407233497,1407233514,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=streamingstats&fmt=n
1407233498,1407233515,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=cenjreaecnjcdmingstats&fmt=n
1407233499,1407233516,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=weedwcecd
```

I compared the speed of my approach compared to yours on a much larger file:

```
$ cat file
1407233497,1407233514,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=streamingstats&fmt=n
1407233498,1407233515,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=cenjreaecnjcd
mingstats&fmt=n
1407233499,1407233516,http://s.youtube.com/stream_204?event=weedwcecd
$ for i in {1..20}; do cat file file > tmp && mv tmp file; done
$ du -h file
242M    file
$ time awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NF>2{if(NR>1)print a,b;a=$1OFS$2;b=$3;next}{b=b$0}END{print a,b}' file > /dev/null 

real    0m13.551s
user    0m13.458s
sys     0m0.069s
$ time awk --re-interval '{printf "%s%s", (NR>1&&/^[0-9]{10}/?"\n":""),$0}END{print ""}' file > /dev/null

real    0m23.438s
user    0m23.331s
sys     0m0.066s
```

As you can see, my approach is much faster.

Comment: very nice answer for your 10K. With testing harness and stats no less! :-).

Comment: I suspect the big performance improvement is due to caching as I don't see anything like as much improvement when I try it, try running each script 3 times before looking at the times as the original only runs that slowly the very first time it's executed. The output you're producing is incorrect anyway, though.

Comment: @Ed thanks for spotting the error in my code. I have updated it so that it now produces the correct output. I have also updated the timings.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;/\n[^,]*$/s/\n//;ta;P;D' file
```

Read 2 lines at a time and if the 2nd line doesn't contain a comma then join it to the first.

Comment: Nice, took about 19 seconds with the above test file.