# join previous line with next depending of pattern of previous line

Tags: sed

I have this Input:

```
1 a
a
2 b b
3 c
c
4 d d
5 e e
6 f
f
7 g
g
```

I want this output using sed command

```
1 a a
2 b b
3 c c
4 d d
5 e e
6 f f
7 g g
```

I'm trying this without success

```
sed '/^[^0-9]/ x; N; { s/\n/ / }; n' file
```

Comment: Try `awk 'BEGIN{ORS=""} NR==1 { print $0" "; next; } /^[[:digit:]]/ { print "\n"; print $0" "; next; }1' file > newfile`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove new line if next line does not begin with a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588113/remove-new-line-if-next-line-does-not-begin-with-a-number)

Comment: `sed -n '$!{ 1{x;d}; H}; ${ H;x;s|\n\([^0-9]\)| \1|g;p}'  file > newfile` works for you.

Comment: `sed '/ .* /b; N; s/\n/ /'` will also work for given input

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=3)print $i,$(i+1),$(i+2)}' file
1 a a
2 b b
3 c c
4 d d
5 e e
6 f f
7 g g
```

Explained:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    RS=""                       # prime awk to read in a paragraph of data
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=3)         # jump forward 3 fields at a time
        print $i,$(i+1),$(i+2)  # print 3 fields
}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

---

```
awk 'NR>1 && /^[0-9]/ {print substr(s,2); s=""} {s=s FS $0} END {print substr(s,2)}' file
```

1. `NR>1 && /^[0-9]/`: If a line is not the first and begins with a digit,
2. `{print substr(s,2); s=""}`: print "s" without the leading space, then clear it.
3. `{s=s FS $0}`: On every line, append the current line to the value of "s". `FS` is a space by default.

*edit*: Added `END` condition to catch last line, hated it, made a better separate answer.

Comment: Last line is missing!

Comment: @ClaesWikner, Good catch, thanks. I made [a better one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56351653/11053344)

Answer (score 1):

Made it simpler with `awk`:

```
awk 'NF==2 {printf("%s ", $0); next} 1' file
```

Basically, "Don't print a newline if there are <s>only</s> exactly two fields."

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^[0-9]/{:a;N;s/\n\([^0-9]\)/ \1/;ta;P;D}' file
```

If the current line begins with an integer,  append the following line. If that line does not begin with an integer, replace the newline by a space and repeat. Otherwise print/delete the first line in the pattern space and repeat.